# Is it safe to allow cross-domain access to all API resources?

Tags: security, api, http, authentication, cors

Access to API resources may be authenticated by

1. Credentials which can be sent automatically by web browsers but won't be sent cross-domain unless Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is set to "true" (e.g. cookies, HTTP Basic/Digest authentication, SSL certificates).
2. A secret token, either in a HTTP header or as a query parameter in the URL, that has to be set manually by the client (e.g. an OAuth access token).

With that in mind, is it always safe to set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" on all resources in an API?

Comment: Essentially, the question is "If an API uses solely OAuth in HTTP headers for authentication, is it safe to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' on all resources?"

Comment: A corollary question, then, would be "Why don't web browsers allow access to all resources cross-domain, as long as no credentials are sent?"

Answer (score 0):

If at any point an attacker executing JavaScript on a domain he controls can obtain data or perform a state change without providing a token then you have a vulnerability.   The attack is very similar to [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29),  except it broadens the horizon to the ex-filtration of data.

But just like CSRF,  if the client must authenticate with a token for each request and the attacker doesn't know this token,  then he can't access the [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) API with a CSRF-like attack.

Comment: Assuming that the only action possible without credentials is reading public data (as it should be), that would mean there is no vulnerabity? There would be no way of sending credentials cross-domain if only "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" is enabled?

Comment: @Alf Eaton you can send data without CORS,  thats the whole idea behind CSRF attacks.  CORS allows you to read data,  and if the attacker doesn't know the key (and the key isn't a cookie),  then he still can't read that data.

Comment: You can send data without CORS, but not without credentials; as long as it's guaranteed that credentials won't be sent automatically, that would mean it's safe to enable CORS headers for all resources.

Comment: @alf Eaton it depends on how the credentials are sent,  an attacker can probably send them,  if he knew what they where...  If its a cookie or even basic auth,  it could be sent automatically, then the attacker wouldn't need to know them.